# How I can extract, or save data from promise

Tags: promise, fetch, save, extract, persist

people please help me with this.
I have an object, and I need to add some data to this object from json file.

```
let data = {
    'test1':1,
    'test2:2
}

function convert(){
fetch("./test.json")
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
})
.then(jsondata => {
    {data = {...data, ...jsondata}}
    console.log(data)
});
}

console.log(data)
```

What I must to do in order to save new version **data**?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just need to do this:

```
data = {...data, ...jsondata};
```

instead of this:

```
{data = {...data, ...jsondata}}
```